# Multiline vim regular expression replacement from range

Tags: regex, vim, multiline

**I am attempting to reformat a hierarchical (xml) file to a "per line" file using vim.**

Here is a simplified example. The real case is "large" (500k lines) and entries and groups are arbitrary counts.

input file:

```
<group key="abc">
  <entry val="1"/>
  <entry val="2"/>
  <entry val="3"/>
</group>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="1"/>
  <entry val="2"/>
  <entry val="3"/>
  <entry val="4"/>
  <entry val="5"/>
</group>
```

output result:

```
abc,1
abc,2
abc,3
xyz,1
xyz,2
xyz,3
xyz,4
xyz,5
```

Please note that I don't need a single magic expression that does all of this (although that'd be swell). The part I am struggling with is getting the key associated with each of the entries. I'm sure there is a good idiom for handling this. Thanks in advance.

**One thing I tried and may be useful to others is as follows:**

```
:g/key="\(.*\)"/.;/<\/group/s/<entry /\1,<entry /g
```

which does not work because the range match is not carried over to the substitution. This expression essentially looks for pat1, builds a range from there to pat2, then substitutes pat3 with pat4 (but only within instances of the pat1,pat2 range inclusive).

```
:g/pat1/.;/pat2/s/pat3/pat4/g
```

**Solution**

The best solution below solved it by looking for the entry and then backwards for the key, as opposed to what I was trying to do above by building a range and multiple substitutions. What finally worked required some minor modifications, so they are provided here for others. The commands that do the heavy lifting are:

```
:g/entry/?key?,\?t.
:g/entry/norm ddpkJ
:v/entry/d
```

Breakdown:

Search for all the entry lines:

```
:g/entry/
```

From there, search backwards for the the line that has the key and copy it below each entry.

```
?key?,\?t.
```

Search for all entry lines again, and switch to normal mode editing

```
:g/entry/norm
```

Swap the two lines (delete key line and paste it below the group line). Move up to the key line and join the two lines.

```
ddpkJ
```

Once all keys are mapped, search for any lines that do NOT have an entry and delete them.

```
:v/entry/d
```

If you have multiple hierarchies as I do, you can run the first two lines multiple times. Once everything is on a single line, it is fairly straightforward to clean it up into whatever final format is needed. Another major benefit is that this solution can be put in a script easily and rerun with

```
vim -S script.vim data.file
```

Comment: One great trick I found that ALMOST gets me started is the expression:

:g/<group key="\(.*\)"/.;/<\/group/s/<entry /\1, <entry /g

which searches for pat1, builds a range from "here" to pat2, then substitutes. :g/pat1/.;/pat2/s/abc/def/g

However, you can't carry over the match from pat1 to the substitution.

Regardless, I did not know about that idiom and wanted to share.

Comment: Just put what you tried in the question. (Formatting would make it look better)

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff. Done. (First post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following would work

```
:g/entry/?<group?,?<group?t.
:%norm J
:g/<\//d
:%norm df"f"df"i,<C-v><Esc>f"d$
```

**Breakdown**

For each line containing `entry`, search backwards for `<group` and copy to the line below entry

```
:g/entry/?<group?,?<group?t.

<group key="abc">
  <entry val="1"/>
<group key="abc">
  <entry val="2"/>
<group key="abc">
  <entry val="3"/>
<group key="abc">
</group>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="1"/>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="2"/>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="3"/>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="4"/>
<group key="xyz">
  <entry val="5"/>
<group key="xyz">
</group>
```

Join all lines

```
:%norm J

<group key="abc"> <entry val="1"/>
<group key="abc"> <entry val="2"/>
<group key="abc"> <entry val="3"/>
<group key="abc"> </group>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="1"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="2"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="3"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="4"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="5"/>
<group key="xyz"> </group>
```

Remove the closing tags

```
:g/<\//d

<group key="abc"> <entry val="1"/>
<group key="abc"> <entry val="2"/>
<group key="abc"> <entry val="3"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="1"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="2"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="3"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="4"/>
<group key="xyz"> <entry val="5"/>
```

Fixup the remaining text by searching and deleting to and from quotes. *Note that `<C-v><Esc>` is the key sequence to add an escape in your command.*

```
:%norm df"f"df"i,<C-v><Esc>f"d$

abc,1
abc,2
abc,3
xyz,1
xyz,2
xyz,3
xyz,4
xyz,5
```

Comment: Could you break down the ?pat?,?pat?t. range expression?

Comment: Instead of :%norm J which depends on the file being perfectly balanced, I did :g/entry/norm kJ which finds all entry lines, moves to the line above with the pasted group and joins them. This supports more than one level.

Comment: Best answer, because it cleverly inverted the search replace I was doing. This also worked well for the case where there were additional hierarchies. Once I got all the data I needed on one line, just :%grep entry cleaned out everything else. Then it's just %s/junk/,/ till done. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. In case you still need the ?pat? range expression explanation, it just searches backwards from the current selected line (an entry line in our case) for a "group" line and sets the range to 1 line (I think that can be shortened but haven't tried it). The "t" copies the range (our one line) below our current line.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the :t command. Synonym with :copy. The range can be shorted as: ?pat?,\? where \? searches for the previous line where the previously used search pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a magical one line but might work:

```
ggqq/groupf"lyi"<c-v>n0I<c-r>"<esc>ddnddq
100@q
:%s/\s*<entry val="/,/g
:%s/"\/>//g
```

Step by step:

```
gg       => Go to the top
qq       => Record a macro called q
/group   => Search for "group"
f"l      => Go to the key
yi"      => Copy the key
c-v      => Vertical visual mode
n0       => Go to the end of the "group", place the cursor at the beginning
I<c-r>"<esc> => Paste at the beginning
dd       => Delete <group> line
ndd      => Delete end </group> line
q        => Stop macro

100@q    => Play macro 100 times, use whatever you need
```

Now you should have something like:

```
abc  <entry val="1"/>
abc  <entry val="2"/>
abc  <entry val="3"/>
xyz  <entry val="1"/>
xyz  <entry val="2"/>
xyz  <entry val="3"/>
xyz  <entry val="4"/>
xyz  <entry val="5"/>
```

Then just clean what you don't need:

```
:%s/\s*<entry val="/,/g
:%s/"\/>//g
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The qq macro idiom is something I hadn't used in awhile. This works well for medium and small files since it's interactive. I was going to have to do a lot of line counting work outside of vim though to figure out how many times to replay the macro for a very large file.